# HEX response with python

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port

I have this code that code to send by a com rs232 port in Hex and i'm getting a symbol response which one doesn't is the same that i could get from the response.... any tip?

```
import serial

port = "COM6"
ser = serial.Serial(port,9600,timeout=0.5)
print(ser.name + ' is open.')

while True:
input = raw_input("Enter HEX cmd or 'exit'>> ")
if input == 'exit':
    ser.close()
    print(port+' is closed.')
    exit()

elif len(input) == 8:
# user enters new register value, convert it into hex
    newRegisterValue = bits_to_hex(input)
    ser.write(newRegisterValue.decode('hex'+'\r\n'))
    print('Saving...'+newRegisterValue)
    print('Receiving...')
    out = ser.read(1)
    for byte in out:
        print(byte) # present byte

else:
    cmd = input
    print('Sending...'+cmd)
    ser.write(cmd.decode('hex')+'\r\n')
    print('Receiving...')
    out = ser.read(1)
    for byte in out:
        print(byte) # present byte
```

Comment: *i'm getting a symbol response which one doesn't is the same that i could get from the response* - Um... What does that mean? Please be more specific about the problem you're having.

Comment: instead of getting the HEX response, i got a symbol, it supposed to get me a 06 and i get a sword symbol

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the details there, instead of burying them in the comments. You don't get a *sword symbol*, because a *sword symbol* is not hex. You may be **displaying** it  incorrectly, but you're not receiving a sword symbol. You're printing the output as a character, not a hex string, and the character for 0x06 is not a printable value. See any ASCII table.

Comment: already try it... and i'm burning out of ideas hahaha